# Git - delete older commit like it and its changes never happened

Tags: git

I want to delete older commit, because I had to separate it to 2 commits.
So changes, that are at `a5b4cd` are same like changes in `2a0d40e` + `a8bb836`.

```
2a0d40e Add sending
a8bb836 Add parsing
a5b4cbd Add sending and parsing     <--- I want to delete this
f6063ac First commit
```

I tried some `git rebase -i` and `fixup` here, but everytime, it will add changes from this "deleted" commit to another commit and that I dont want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove local commit completely from tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984814/remove-local-commit-completely-from-tree)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use fixup. Simply remove that line during your [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode).

That will be enough for that commit to be dropped.

But then be prepared to have to force push ([`git push --force`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push--f)) which can be problematic on public branches.

Another option would be [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) (if you just want to cancel that commit rather than remove it from the history completely)

> Before rebasing when I wanted to separate them I got Commit2 with File3 and File4. Then I wanted to separate it, so I have deleted File4, add Commit3 (just with File1 and File3), then added File4 and make Commit4.

Then the solution is different: While at Commit 4 (with all your files), do a

```
git reset --soft Commit1
git add File3
git commit -m "Add File3"
git add File4
git commit -m "Add File4"
```

Comment: I tried removing line, but I get: 'The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.' and 'Could not apply a8bb836... Add parsing'.

Comment: @Mildas What git version are you using? (since this was discussed before: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/odd-behavior-with-git-rebase-td7399607.html)

Comment: @Mildas Considering http://stackoverflow.com/a/29638001/6309, you could try and drop as well a8bb836, and see if the final result is still what you want.

Comment: git version 2.7.4. And I tried as you said dropping a8bb836 too (both lines at one rebase) and then it successfully rebases, but then at log is only first and last commit.

Comment: @Mildas Yes, that is the expected result. The question is: do you see al the files and content you want after such a rebase (dropping both commits)?

Comment: There are not changes from a8bb836. Only changes from that commit, that I didnt delete at rebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137589/discussion-between-vonc-and-mildas).