# Delete Git Commits - most recent one and an older one

Tags: git, commit

I have seen multiple answers on deleting most recent commit but can't find any where an older commit is deleted as well.

I have the last four commits as:

```
bc8354f Revert Merge branch 'repo/develop' into M372046"
edce31a Good commit2 M372046
926b7de Good commit1 M372046
422f6cb Merge branch 'repo/develop' into M372046
```

I want to delete bc8354f and 422f6cb without affecting others.

I have tried :
git rebase -i HEAD~4
but it only shows bc8354f and not the other one.
If i delete that commit using d, drop= remove commit, it puts me to a HEAD reference of that original branch and don't know how to make it take effect, nor do I know how to delete the 422f6cb commit.

If I try to push this HEAD ref to the original (M372046) I get :
This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.

error: failed to push some refs to ...

I have also tried deleting the entire line that starts with "pick" when doing a rebase but when I save it it says "Nothing to do" and no changes are made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove local commit completely from tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984814/remove-local-commit-completely-from-tree)

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase -i HEAD~4` should show you all 4 commits. But beware, rebase will usually not show merge commits. If you then delete the lines containing the commits you want to delete (or change them to `drop`) you should get the expected result.

Another way would be to reset your branch to `422f6cb^` (the 5th last commit) and then cherry pick both `edce31a` and `926b7de`

Comment: This won't work for my situation. Even though I reset it back to a point before the above merge and revert, it tries to over-write those files of the merge with an older state. There seems to be no way of setting those merge files to an untouched state even when reseting before the merge. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

```
git branch tmp
git reset --hard HEAD~4
git cherry-pick tmp~2
git cherry-pick tmp~1
```

after which you should inspect the result carefully, and if all looks good, delete branch `tmp`.  You must then force-push (`git push -f` or equivalent) to discard all the work everyone (including you) has done since the commit you `git reset` to, in favor of the copies you just made.  ***Be sure no one else has done work and pushed commits that must be kept.***

(Check the long answer below, and make sure the graph really is the way I have drawn it, before blindly doing this.)

#### Long

Technically, you cannot *delete* a commit at all.  You can only *stop using it* (and if you've removed all names by which Git can *find* it, it will eventually be recycled via `git gc`, the Grim <strike>Reaper</strike> Collector).

> I want to delete `bc8354f` and `422f6cb` without affecting others.

You cannot do that *at all*, for the technical reason above.  Each existing commit is quite unchangeable.  Meanwhile, commit `926b7de`, which is one you do not want to affect, lists commit `422f6cb` as its parent.

If `422f6cb` did not exist—if you somehow deleted it—commit `926b7de` would become generally unusable, as it would list a parent that does not exist.  (Git can do a few things with a broken commit like this, but the repository would be defective.)

What this means is that in order to delete the merge and its reversion, you *must* be willing to *copy* the two commits you would like to retain.  The copies will be different in at least one respect: the copy of `926b7de` (which will have some different hash-ID) will list some *other* parent than `422f6cb`.

There are some bits-and-pieces missing here, that we (or you) will need to find out / fill in, in order to do what you want.  The first step in almost anything like this, though, is to draw, on paper or a whiteboard or some such, the *commit graph*, or enough of it to matter.  Draw each commit as a *node* with arrows coming out of it.  The arrows should point to the *previous* node(s): the parent(s) of that commit.

I like to put the commits right (latest) to left (oldest), with the arrows pointing leftward.  You can choose some other orientation: for instance, `git log --graph` starts with the newest commits at the top, and the arrows point downward.

An ordinary commit has only a single parent.  The last three of your commits here are ordinary:

```
             <-926b7de  <-edce31a  <-bc8354f
```

Let's replace these with single uppercase letters since the hash IDs are clunky.  We can use `E` and `B` for the last two, since that's the first character of their actual hash IDs, and `B` can stand for Bad.  Let's use `D` for the first of these three, since it ends in `DE`:

```
             <-D        <-E        <-B
```

Now we have `422f6cb Merge branch 'repo/develop' into M372046`, though.  This one is a *merge commit*.  A merge commit is special in that it has two (or more, but ordinary merges only have two) parents.

I don't know their hash IDs so I'll just draw `M`, the Merge commit, this way:

```
...
   \
    M        <-D        <-E        <-B
   /
...
```

and then I'll tweak the drawing a bit for reasons we'll see in a moment, and add some branch names as well:

```
...--o
      \
       M--D--E--B   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
      /
...--o   <-- repo/develop
```

Note that the branch names, `yourbranch`—whatever branch this is; it's the one that your `HEAD` is attached to—and `repo/develop`, point to *one specific commit*.  This is the *tip* commit of the corresponding branch.  This is how Git finds the commits: it starts at the tip, as found by the branch *name*, and then uses the commit hashes embedded in each commit to work backwards through this graph.

Now, you want to get rid of commit `M` (the merge) and commit `B` (the bad commit that undoes the merge) entirely.  You *can* do this, sort of, by simply *forgetting about them* by making the name `yourbranch` point directly to whichever commit comes before `M` on the top row:

```
...--o   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
      \
       M--D--E--B   [abandoned]
      /
...--o   <-- repo/develop
```

There is now no *name* for commit `B`, so you won't find it.  But since you won't find `B`, you won't find `E` and `D` either.  Of course that also means you won't find `M`, but that's OK: you wanted that!  But dropping `D` and `E` is the actual problem.  So we will need to fix that.

First, though, let's learn how to move the branch *name*, `yourbranch` (to which your HEAD is attached), so that it points to the commit just before `M` along the top row.  The command that does this is `git reset`.  The `git reset` command does a lot of things—too many things, in my opinion—but this is one of the things it will do.  We make sure that we have no unsaved work and run:

```
git reset --hard <hash>
```

to change the branch name to which our `HEAD` is attached so that it points to the given `<hash>` commit.  So we must find the appropriate parent, and do the `git reset`, and we'll have the picture we want as our intermediate step.

Now—well, technically, *before* we do this—we must save the hash IDs of the commits we want to *copy*, or attach a name to the last one, or anything that comes after the last one.  The easier method, in general, is to attach a name, because then we can use `git rebase -i --onto` to copy commits en-masse.  Let's do it the harder way instead, though, because that's more instructive.

The command that copies a commit is `git cherry-pick`.  It turns a commit—a snapshot—into a set of changes, by comparing the commit to its parent.  That is, given commit `E`, it will compare `D` vs `E` to see what you changed.  It will save those changes away, and then look at your *current* commit—the one you have checked-out right now—and apply the *same* changes and then make a new commit.

Now, before we run `git reset`, let's attach a *second* branch name `tmp` here, using `git branch`:

```
git branch tmp

...--o
      \
       M--D--E--B   <-- yourbranch (HEAD), tmp
      /
...--o   <-- repo/develop
```

Then when we do the `git reset --hard`, `tmp` will remain:

```
...--o   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
      \
       M--D--E--B   <-- tmp
      /
...--o   <-- repo/develop
```

The name `tmp` will keep the commits alive.

There's a fancy way to name the commit on the top row.  We know that `tmp` and, before the `git reset` command anyway, `yourbranch` aka `HEAD`, both identify commit `B`.  If we step back one parent from `B`, we get to `E`.  If we step back 2 parents, we get to `D`.  If we step back three, we get to `M`.  If we step back four ... well, now we have a problem: which *direction* do we step back: left-and-up, or left-and-down?

The answer Git gives is that we can choose which way to go, at a merge.  The *default* answer is to move to the "first parent".  The *first* parent of any merge is the commit that was at the tip of the branch before you did the merge.  In our case, that's the one that's also upwards, which is what we want.

The special syntax `~number` means *count back that many first-parent links*.  So, `HEAD~4` means *start at HEAD and go back four first-parent links*, which arrives at the commit we want.

Now we can use `git cherry-pick` to make *copies* of the good commits that we wish to keep.  Note that we should do them in what Git thinks of as *reverse* order, i.e., do the *older* one first, instead of the *newer* one first, in case commit `E` depends on commit `D`.

To copy commit `E`, simply name it in a `git cherry-pick` command.  Note that `tmp` names commit `B`, `tmp~1` names `E`, and `tmp~2` names `D`, so:

```
git cherry-pick tmp~2
git cherry-pick tmp~1
```

will copy `D` and then `E`, giving:

```
...--o--D'-E'  <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
      \
       M--D--E--B   <-- tmp
      /
...--o   <-- repo/develop
```

where `D'` and `E'` are the copies you just made.

It's now safe to delete `tmp`:

```
git branch -D tmp
```

(well, as long as everything looks good—you can delete `tmp` later, of course).

Comment: Awesome, in-depth answer and explenation. +1!